# How do I modify WordPress such that the Facebook crawler can't see my canonical tags?

Tags: wordpress, canonical-url

I get content from an external sources via RSS.
I've set "canonical" so google knows the content is not original.

However when I post the link of my articles on Facebook, I get the original URL post instead.

How should I edit my WordPress?

Comment: This appears to be a followup question from [How do you share a non-canonical URL on Facebook?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69784/how-do-you-share-a-non-canonical-url-on-facebook)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook crawls the page when the link is shared in Facebook.  Facebook uses a `facebookexternalhit` user agent when it does so.  See [Facebook Bot User Agents](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/facebook-bot/) for a list of full user agent strings it uses.  You would need to remove this canonical for this user agent.

To make that happen in WordPress you should be able to edit `functions.php` with code similar to:

```
if (preg_match('/facebookexternalhit/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');
}
```

Code sources:

- [Disable WordPress canonical tag meta - WordPress Development Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137233/disable-wordpress-canonical-tag-meta)
- [Conditonal statement for iPad - WordPress Development Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20857/conditonal-statement-for-ipad)